# Will [a-z]* redirect work in the httpd.conf

Tags: linux, apache, apache-config, httpd.conf

Will this redirect work [a-z]* to example.com

ie., I want to redirect anything to example.com

Thanks Jean

Answer (score 1):

`.*`  A period matches any character except a newline.

But what you probably want is:

`Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/`

Comment: Can I add this to the httpd.conf directory?

Comment: You can add it directly to the httpd.conf file, or to your .htaccess file depending on what exactly you want.